# Automated switch PowerPoint 4x3 to 16x9

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net, powerpoint

I have roughly 1,000 PowerPoint presentations that were created in 4x3 format that I would like to switch to 16x9.  They mostly consist of a title and text box below on each slide with an average of 5 slides per presentation.

I know I can go in and adjust the layout to switch the presentation ... but doing 1,000 of them one at a time is going to be *very* time consuming.

Is there any way using ASP, VB, or PHP that I can do this automatically?  I know I'll still likely need to go in and do some clean-up but at least this would get the first chunk of the process done ... hopefully easily!

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of PPT do you have and are the results satisfactory if you open a few of these presentations and manually change the slide size?

Comment: It's PPT 2013 ... and the results are "adequate" ... not perfect but close enough when we manually switch them over to 16x9.

Comment: See my suggested answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a routine to do something to every file in a folder on my PPTFAQ site:

Batch: Do something to every file in a folder
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00536_Batch-_Do_something_to_every_file_in_a_folder.htm

It first creates a list of the files to be processed then hands the names off one at a time to another routine called MyMacro that does the actual work on each presentation.  Replace the version of MyMacro on the web site with this:

```
Sub MyMacro(strMyFile As String)
' this gets called once for each file that meets the spec you enter in ForEachPresentation
' strMyFile is set to the file name each time

    Dim oPresentation As Presentation
    Set oPresentation = Presentations.Open(strMyFile)

    With oPresentation
        .PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen16x9
        .SaveAs .Path & "\" & "Widescreen_" & .Name
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

It'll change the presentation to 16x9 format and save it to the original directory with "Widescreen_" prepended to the original file name.  For example, MyFile.PPTX will be saved as Widescreen_MyFile.PPTX

Comment: Nice simple solution.  I didn't realize it was quite that easy.  I'll likely adjust your main routine to not do a redim everytime as I can get a count of the number of files ahead of time just by looking at the file count for the directory.  I'll also likely create a sub-directory to put all the adjusted files into ... but the code is simple and clean ... and exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Definitely feel free to adjust/improve/repurpose as needed.  Glad it helped.